# Application insights is unable to download nuget packages

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am unable to launch application insights status monitor due to error listed below. I tried reinstaling the application (there were no issues during instalation), made sure I lounch it as admin, even tried to plaz around with nuget package mannager in VS, but was unable to solve the issue. Can anyone help me?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ONWu.png)

Full text of an error detail:

> An unhandled exception occurred: System.AggregateException: Došlo k
> jedné nebo více chybám. --->  System.InvalidOperationException: An
> error occurred while loading packages from
> 'https://packages.nuget.org/ api/v2': Nadřízené připojení bylo
> uzavřeno: Došlo k neočekávané chybě při odeslání. --->
> System.Net.WebException: Nadřízené připojení bylo uzavřeno: Došlo k
> neočekávané chybě při odeslání. --->  System.IO.IOException: Nelze
> číst data z přenosového připojení: Stávající připojení bylo vynuceně
> ukončeno  vzdáleným hostitelem. --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Stávající připojení bylo vynuceně
> ukončeno  vzdáleným hostitelem    v
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    --- Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---
> v System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    v System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message,  AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
> Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest  asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback  callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state)    v
> System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
> v System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> v System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> size)    v System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    ---
> Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---    v
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    v
> NuGet.RequestHelper.GetResponse()    v
> NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.GetResponseUri(HttpClient client)    v
> NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.EnsureClient()    v
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    v System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()    v
> NuGet.MemoryCache.GetOrAdd[T](Object cacheKey, Func`1 factory, TimeSpan expiration, Boolean  absoluteExpiration)    v NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_CachedClient()    v NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_Uri()    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.get_Context()    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)  --- Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)  v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackagesById(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId)    v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackages(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId,  IVersionSpec versionSpec, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)    v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId,  IVersionSpec versionSpec, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)    v Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.NugetExtension.PackageManagerExtension.FindPackage(String packageName, String source, Boolean allowPrerelease, String version)   v Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.NugetExtension.PackageManagerExtension.DownloadPackage(String packageName, String source, Boolean allowPrerelease, String outputDirectory, IList`1 frameworkNames, String  version, Action`1 progressAction)    v  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadPackage (String packageName, String packageVersion, String targetDirectory, Boolean includeDirectory, Action`1  progressAction)    v
> Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadLatestStatu
> sMonitorPackage(Action`1 progressAction)    v  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadLatestPack ages(Action`1 progressAction)    v
> Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.MainWindow.DoStartupUpgrade(Object
> state)    v System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()    --- Konec
> trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---    v
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    v
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    v
> Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.MainWindow.<.ctor>b__0_0()
> v System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback  callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state)    v
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while loading packages from
> 'https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2': Nadřízené připojení bylo
> uzavřeno: Došlo k neočekávané chybě při odeslání.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: Nadřízené připojení bylo uzavřeno: Došlo k neočekávané chybě při odeslání. --->  System.IO.IOException: Nelze
> číst data z přenosového připojení: Stávající připojení bylo vynuceně
> ukončeno  vzdáleným hostitelem. --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Stávající připojení bylo vynuceně
> ukončeno  vzdáleným hostitelem    v
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    --- Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---
> v System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    v System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message,  AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
> Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest  asyncRequest)    v
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback  callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    v
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object  state)    v
> System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
> v System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> v System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> size)    v System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    ---
> Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---    v
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    v
> NuGet.RequestHelper.GetResponse()    v
> NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.GetResponseUri(HttpClient client)    v
> NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.EnsureClient()    v
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    v System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()    v
> NuGet.MemoryCache.GetOrAdd[T](Object cacheKey, Func`1 factory, TimeSpan expiration, Boolean  absoluteExpiration)    v NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_CachedClient()    v NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_Uri()    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.get_Context()    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)  --- Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---    v NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)  v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackagesById(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId)    v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackages(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId,  IVersionSpec versionSpec, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)    v NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId,  IVersionSpec versionSpec, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)    v Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.NugetExtension.PackageManagerExtension.FindPackage(String packageName, String source, Boolean allowPrerelease, String version)   v Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.NugetExtension.PackageManagerExtension.DownloadPackage(String packageName, String source, Boolean allowPrerelease, String outputDirectory, IList`1 frameworkNames, String  version, Action`1 progressAction)    v  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadPackage (String packageName, String packageVersion, String targetDirectory, Boolean includeDirectory, Action`1  progressAction)    v
> Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadLatestStatu
> sMonitorPackage(Action`1 progressAction)    v  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.PackageManager.PackageManagerImpl.DownloadLatestPack ages(Action`1 progressAction)    v
> Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Upgrade.MainWindow.DoStartupUpgrade(Object
> state)    v System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Answer (score 0):

This old component has been replaced with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview. Please try that instead to enable Application Insights.